# CSS - stick to bottom of iOS Safari when scrolling

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari

I am building an app and I would like to have a navbar stuck to the bottom of the browser. I have something like

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%"
  <header>Header</header>
  <section style="height: 100%">Main Content</section>
  <footer>Sticky footer</footer>
<div>
```

This works great for desktop. Here is a simple example where red is header, yellow is footer, blue is content.

[image]

However, in iOS Safari (and some Android browsers I think too) when you scroll, there bottom 44px or so is covered by the toolbar.

[image]

I read [here](https://www.eventbrite.com/engineering/mobile-safari-why/) and some others about workarounds, but no real "good" solution. However, is seems Instagram's website on iOS solved this:

Without scrolling:

[image]

When you scroll the bottom nav repositions above the toolbar nicely:

[image]

One solution is just make the toolbar always visible, but I would like to take the Instagram style approach. I am not sure how to implement in CSS (or CSS + JS). Does anyone know how I can achieve the Instagram effect? The bottom navbar wrt to the Safari iOS toolbar moves seemlessly when you scroll.

Edit: here is the working demo that solves this problem.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html style="height:100%"lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title></title>

    </head>
    <body style="height:100%; padding: 0; margin: 0">
      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%">
        <header>Header</header>
        <div>
          <div>Main content</div>
        </div>
        <footer style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%">Sticky footer</footer>
      </div>  
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the `height: 100%;`. Do you mean the page is of 100vh?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10; /** this value affects the overlapping **/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Actually it's not an overlapping problem - the bottom navbar (iOS one) is not part of the DOM, but the actual app shell, so it will always be on top.

Comment: This answer seems to be correct. Even the instagram website uses this code. I tried the same [here](https://s.codepen.io/gibinealias/debug/BYyNxp/mWMoNbQDLOyk) and worked fine with iPhone 6, 6s and 6+.
The footer will always stick to the bottom of the page and when the iOS nav bar is visible, it positions right above it and won't overlap.
Finally, we may add a `margin-bottom` to the container/page so that the bottom contents won't be overlapped by our footer (not the iOS one).

Comment: Woah, really? Maybe I was doing something wrong. I will give this a try today and report back. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: Hey, this worked for me after all. Thanks Lucas. I'll post a snippet in the question of the final code.

Comment: Actually this only works esthetically. You'll need to press twice to activate the click event if the bottom navigation bar was not already showing.

Comment: Thanks!! That helped me a lot